# Using require() inside define() requireJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, module, requirejs

a module I've build just needs dependencies in one case. So I load the dependencies of this module only if I need them in a `init()`-function of the module like:

```
define([], function(){
    function init(){
        // Case for dependencies
        if(1 == 1){
            require(
                ["config", "logging", "jquery", "mediator", "request", "selectivizr"],
                function(config, logging, jQuery, mediator, request) {
                    console.log("Initializing BaseApp");
                }
            );
        }
        return {};
    }
    return init();
});
```

The problem is, that I can see in the log, the modules will sometimes be initialized **after** the callback function was called. So a log output could be:

```
"10:46:30  Logging initialized"
"10:46:30  Initializing BaseApp"
"10:46:30  Loading Mediator"
"10:46:30  Initializing Request"
```

What can I do?

Comment: The log you show does not correspond to the code you show. So you should post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, rather than the one fragment of code you have. Also, the output you show looks like it is a combination of pure `console.log` calls plus something produced by a logger (log4javascript maybe?) Replace all that with straight calls to `console.log` and *show us* those calls. Otherwise, we're going to be chasing after issues that may be with the logger you are using.

Comment: Better than it was but what causes the lines other than "Initializing BaseApp" to be output? Show the code that causes these lines. It may mean including at least some of the code of the relevant modules.

Comment: Well there is nothing to show, they are modules like everyone with a init function and logging "Initializing", like my example.

Comment: I've got over 50 modules designed to load with RequireJS, I use dozens of modules by third parties, and *not a single one of them* outputs anything to the console to indicate that they are loaded. So, no, your modules are not "modules like everyone".